# Development of IoT device for an MS Electrical Engineering thesis

Tags: thesis, masters, electrical-engineering

Is it a good idea to design and develop an Internet of things (IoT) device instead of investigation of a theoretical research problem for an MS Electrical Engineering thesis?

Majority of the MS Electrical and Computer Engineering theses investigate a current research problem and usually involve simulations to report results. So, there is a level of novelty in that it is a current research problem. However, design and development of an IoT device, may not involve that level of newness or novelty. The IoT device under question is a new device with sufficient complexity but has already been designed and developed somewhere else. On the other hand, it is a practical implementation and not a mere simulation. So, how would you recommend an MS student going for this type of thesis? How would the examiners look at this type of thesis?

Comment: It's best to ask your supervisor about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd get out of the mindset of describing the attributes that some solution for some problem should have, and identify a problem you might find fun to attempt to solve.

Once you have the problem to be solved, you can engineer the solution to meet the requirements.  Problems exist everywhere, if you only look for them.  Find something that's your "itch" you've been meaning to "scratch" and then build a plan around that.

Once you have some of a plan, you might realize that it's a bad choice.  If so, do it again with a different plan.  In short time, you'll have two or three backup plans in addition to the one plan you'll want to promote.

Comment: Decades of software engineering is speaking here.  At least more in the early days, we would often get broad sweeping directives to "get into this" or "do something with that" with vague directions on what the "something" to be accomplished was.  In reality, you can't build anything that's not described enough in detail to know if you built it.  The only way out is to find a real problem, and then start mocking a solution, and then see if your solution sensibly has the characteristics you want.